# How to interact with an element with an id like this: "inputText115:3551;a" using Selnium + webdriverIO + nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, salesforce-lightning

I have an element that is in a Sales-Force Lightening Application that is an HTML application. The element is a text field.

I need to get data into the test field. This is the id of the text field (as follows):

```
inputText115:3551;a
```

The issue I am having is this: "3551" might as well be "WXYZ" or "ABCD" because this value is a dynamic value that is generated by the application (and Sales-Force Lightening is full of this everywhere in their applications). It makes it difficult to test it with selenium because depending on the browser and the session ID, this value changes.

SO far I have not been able to do it.
I have tried:

```
.click('[href="#/sObject/0012C000004TMmQQAW/view"]') <-- by href
.click('/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/span/a')  <-- by xpath
```

So far, nothing has worked for me.

How can I interact/select an element in selenium using NodeJS with a dynamic ID??

Comment: What do you mean by nothing worked? It didn't find the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u have a Label before to the input field, u can find using label text. Usually the first input tag following a label is its text box

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <label class="label" id="usernamelabel">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputText115:3551;a">
</div>
```

You can find it using

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Username']/following::input[1]"));`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to get the parent element of the one who's dynamically changing it's ID and then use some other attribute as it's class or tag name to get it.

I know your question is about node but I'll make an example in java because is the one I've tried Selenium with and I think that the idea is what is useful for you here.
i.e. for the following HTML assuming that you have a *div* element as a parent of your *input* element:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" id="inputText115:3551;a">
</div>
```

you can do some navigation through it's parent element like this:

```
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDiv"));
parentElement.findElement(By.tagName("input")).click(); //here you're clicking the element with the changing ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You either specify some selector or select all elements with an ID and filter the right one using a regex. Some useful tips:

Google Chrome developer console has neat options when right clicking on an element on the Elements tab:

- Copy >

  - Copy selector (for css)
  - Copy XPath

However in your case these might not help, as they search for the nearest parent with an ID node and use relative path to that one.

You can experiment with XPath and CSS selectors in the console: Chrome Dev Console has two functions in the scope: `$$` and `$x`. The first can be used to test CSS selectors, the second to test XPath.